# Append matrix to another matrix in Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix M=[4 3 2 1;1 2 3 4]. I want to append different size matrices at each iteration:

```
M=[4 3 2 1;1 2 3 4];
for i=1:t
newM=createNewMatrix;
 M=[M;newM];
end
```

newM can be [] or a Nx4 matrix. This is very slow though. What is the fastest way to do this?

**Update**

Pre-allocating would look like this?

```
M=zeros(200000,4)
start=1
M(1:2,:)=M=[4 3 2 1;1 2 3 4];
for i=1:t
newM=createNewMatrix;
size_of_newM=size(newM,1);
finish=start+size_of_newM-1;
M(start:finish,:)=newM;
start=finish;
end
```

Comment: The fastest way is to preallocate the final matrix. Due to how they're implemented in memory, cell arrays may be faster (also depends on your MATLAB version) than concatenating numeric matrices. See [this Undocumented MATLAB article](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/array-resizing-performance).

Comment: i updated question to verify what you are suggesting

Comment: What does `createNewMatrix` do? Maybe that's slow. Have you tried to make a random matrix and see what the speed is like then? But also, preallocation is a definite first step

Comment: Do you need to access extended `M` on each iteration ? Maybe putting individual `createNewMatrix` in a preallocated cell array and then calling [`cell2mat`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) only once in the end can be sufficient (and fast) ?

Comment: @Dan Assume that `createNewMatrix ` as a black box function. It is the essence of the  job and "cannot change" the way it is implemented. It is indeed a time-consuming function but at least i can save some time by doing something right.

Comment: @CitizenInsane Yes, I need to access M within the loop

Answer (score 1):

Like suggested, preallocation gives the most boost.
Using cell arrays is another good approach and could be implemented like this:

```
M = cell(200000, 1);
M{1} = [4 3 2 1; 1 2 3 4];
for t=2:200000 
    i = randi(3)-1;
    M{t}=rand(i,4); 
end
MC = vertcat(M{:});
```

In principle you generate a cell array with arbitrary long arrays in each cell and then concatenate them afterwards.
This worked for me nearly twice as fast as your preallocation update. On the other hand, this still was only around one second for the example with 200k iterations...